# i have one method (example: Read() ) in one JFrame , now i want to use the same method in new JFrame (say example: JFrame2). How can I do that?

Tags: java, jframe

**Dataset.java**

```
package base_project;

import ....

public class Dataset extends javax.swing.JFrame {

     public Dataset() {
    initComponents();
    addRowToJTable();
}

static ArrayList<a> ar = new ArrayList<a>();

 public void Read()
 { 
 }

public void addRowToJTable()
{
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTableDataset.getModel();
    Read();

    String Data[][]=new String[ar.size()][12];       
           for (int i=0;i<ar.size();i++)
           { }
 }

 private void jButtonDSNextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    Classification c = new Classification();
    c.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false); 
} 

 public static void main(String args[]) {
 }
```

This is my first JFrame form which is named as Dataset.java . In this file i have used Read() method. This file contains one buttton which leads to next JFrame called **Classification**. The code of Classification.java is as follows:

**Classification.java**

```
package base_project;

import ....

public class Classification extends javax.swing.JFrame {

     public Classification() {
    initComponents();
    addRowToJTable();
}

static ArrayList<a> ar = new ArrayList<a>();
static ArrayList<q> aq = new ArrayList<q>();
static ArrayList<s> as = new ArrayList<s>();


public static void Read()
{}

public static void Set_Q()
{}

public static void Set_s()
{}

public void addRowToJTable()
{
    DefaultTableModel modelQID = (DefaultTableModel) jTableQID.getModel();
    DefaultTableModel modelSA = (DefaultTableModel) jTableSA.getModel();

    Read();
    Set_Q();
    Set_s();

    String DataQ[][]=new String[aq.size()][6];       
    for (int i=0;i<aq.size();i++)
        {

        }

    String DataS[][]=new String[as.size()][6];       
    for (int i=0;i<as.size();i++)
    {

    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
}
```

This runs fine. But the problem is that i have to again write the whole **Read()** method in this Classification.java also. So eachtime whenever i want to use that method i have to again write it in every new JFrame , which i don't want. So what can i do to avoid that?

I'm no expert in java so please bear with me. I've tried looking through the java docs and on this site but cannot seem to find a solution to my problem.

THANKS in advance.

Comment: you can always call it, but then I would recommend refactoring the code and storing that method in a (shared) (parent)class, or a utility class.

Comment: post the method code

Comment: @SteelToe    posted

Comment: I think, you are simply asking for code reusability among two classes. You need to tell what does `Read()` method do.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few things that are a little confusing, as followd:

Firstly, there should only ever be one public static void main(String args[]) {} method because this is the start of the program which there can only ever be one.

Secondly, when a class extends another class it shares all of the methods in the super class. This is what you are doing when you go "Classification extends JFrame" and "Dataset extends JFrame" both classes now technically have the same methods, plus whatever you add on top in each class.
Therefore, one of the key OOP principals is that if two classes share the exact same code, you put that code in the super class. In this case both classes extend JFrame, but you cannot edit JFrame as it is part of the existing Java API. Therefore, to make the read() method common between both files, you should create a wrapper such as (AbstractReadFrame.java):

```
public abstract class AbstractReadFrame extends JFrame {
    // AbstractReadFrame shares all methods within JFrame
    public void read() {
        // code for reading, this is shared between all classes which extends AbstractReadFrame
    }
    // other common code
}


public class Classification extends AbstractReadFrame {
    // shares all methods within AbstractReadRame and JFrame
    public void addRowToJTable() {
        DefaultTableModel modelQID = (DefaultTableModel) jTableQID.getModel();
        DefaultTableModel modelSA = (DefaultTableModel) jTableSA.getModel();

        Read();// calls read() in AbstractReadFrame
        Set_Q();
        Set_s();

        String DataQ[][] = new String[aq.size()][6];
        for (int i = 0; i < aq.size(); i++) {

        }

        String DataS[][] = new String[as.size()][6];
        for (int i = 0; i < as.size(); i++) {

        }
    }
    // other code
}

public class Dataset extends AbstractReadFrame {
    // shares all methods within AbstractReadRame and JFrame
    public void addRowToJTable() {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTableDataset.getModel();
        Read(); // calls read() in AbstractReadFrame

        String Data[][] = new String[ar.size()][12];
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++) {
        }
    }

    // other code
}
```

However, in classification.java you have declared read() to be static which means it will not be work with in the way i have mentioned above. I'd recommend reading about inheritance in Java (such as https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm)
as this will help you a lot with structuring your program.

By having the super class hold all common code, you only have to write it once and run it whenever you wish.

Comment: thanks @John   here i am posting my code hope i can make you clear by that

Comment: `public class Dataset extends javax.swing.JFrame { public void Read() { } } `

Comment: this is the Dataset.java file in which i am using Read() and in this file , by using button i am going to another file which is Classification.java but in that file also i need this Read() function..... so i have to again write it in classification file.. so instead of writing it again there i need some solution

Comment: Here is the classification.java file

Comment: `public class Classification extends javax.swing.JFrame { public static void Read( ) { } public static void Set_QIDs() {} }`

Comment: Someone please help me out !

Comment: Its still a little blurry what you are trying to achieve, are you able to post the respective classes?

Comment: I have edited my code...I'm sorry if I haven't explained it very well, I'm fairly new to Java if you need any clarification please let me know and I'll do my best to clarify it.